# Session State feature missing in iis7

Tags: iis-7

I'm trying to work with the Session State feature using the IIS Manager in IIS7, but I can't see it and I have no idea how to make it appear.  I'm using IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacentre.  Any ideas?

```
Windows Server Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
IIS Version 7.5.7600.16385
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ASP.Net installed, it should appear under the server node, under ASP.NET:

[image: Session State Icon]

Comment: Ah.  Turns out I didn't have ASP.Net installed.  Given the site I am running is an ASP.Net site, this seems odd!